# Trigger function when two bootstrap buttons are selected (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

Please forgive the beginner question, your help is very much appreciated.

I am working with the following template:
http://www.prepbootstrap.com/bootstrap-template/multi-select-buttons

What I would like to do is redirect to a different page if two specific buttons are clicked. 
My solution would be:

1) Add the class "active" to the div associated with a button when it is clicked. 
As I understand this might be unnecessary since the activate class is added automatically because of the inclusion of data-toggle="button" 
Is that indeed the case, or do I need to add the activate class, with the following?:

```
<button onclick="activate()">
```

and then, in the JS file,

```
 function activate() {
    ( this ).toggleClass( "active" );
    };
```

2) Trigger a function (redirect) if two specific buttons that have the class active (i.e. when they have been clicked/selected).

To do so: 
I would first enclose each button with a div with a distinct Id to differentiate them: for instance, I would enclose the car button with `<button id="car"></div>`

Second, I would add the following function to redirect if the requirements are met:

```
function redirect() {
if document.getElementById("car").hasClass('active') && (document.getElementById("truck").hasClass('active')=== true) 
{
location.href = "http://www.google.com";
}
};
```

Could someone please tell me if I am on the right track?

Sorry if my noob solution is overly verbose, thanks again, Andre

Comment: What you need are *checkboxes* that look like buttons.

Answer (score 0):

try this
give each box an id
then assign a count variable
and whenever the button is clicked 
Check whether active class is enabled already or not
If already enabled then put count--;
If not change the className to active and increase the count by 1 ie. count++;
and at the same time check whether count value is 2 if so implement redirect function.
For example,

```
var count=0; 
function activate() { 
    if(this.className=="active"){  
       ( this ).toggleClass( "active" );  
       count--; 
    }else{  
        ( this ).toggleClass( "active" ); 
        count++;  
    }  
    if(count>1){
        //implement redirect function  
    } 
};
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Robert, will give it a try!

Comment: I am not Robert

Comment: Seems like my problem is also related to my redirect function: 

    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function redirect() {
    if document.getElementById("car").hasClass("active") && (document.getElementById("key").hasClass("active")=== true) 
    {
    window.location = "http://www.google.com";
    }
    };

I know there is a problem with this function since the redirect does not occur even when I modify the hasClass selector to something hard coded in the HTMLsuch as hasClass("items"), which does not depend on the activate function

Comment: well if you find your answer is correct one please click that "tick" so that others can know its the correct answer

Comment: This question has been active for past two years
If you find this answer is correct one, please click that "tick" so that others can know its the correct answer

Answer (score 0):

Seems like I was looking for something too complicated. Since clicking on my checkbox buttons already triggered the class 'active', all I had to do was to correct my redirect function, as this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function redirect() {
if ((document.getElementById('car').classList.contains('active')) && (document.getElementById('truck').classList.contains('active')) == true) {
     window.location = "https://www.websitetoredirecto.com";
};
    };
</script>
```

Thanks for the help, Andre